# how to migrate a squashfs system to another filesystem that's read/write

Tags: linux, filesystems, busybox

Well, basically what i want to do is copy all of my router's files (even the dev file (because i'm running busybox)) to my usb flash drive and let my router by default boot from the usb device. it might be not as fast as the nand flash that my router boots from, but i want to access the router's file any time and edit the files of the router.

also, i don't want to mount it as squashfs, but as a filesystem the router understands, as it is currently running busybox v1.9.1 and has linux 2.6.15-17 (don't exactly remember), and i want the new filesystem to be read/write.

here's the output of the mount command:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw)
/proc on /proc type proc (rw)
none on /var type tmpfs (rw)
none on /tmp type tmpfs (rw)
none on /mnt type tmpfs (rw)
usbfs on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw)
/dev/nandflash on /upgflash type ext3 (rw,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/usb1_1 type vfat (rw,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,codepage=cp936,iocharset=cp936,shortname=winnt)
none on /html/help type tmpfs (rw)
```

and the output of the df -k command:

```
Filesystem           1k-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                    8320      8320         0 100% /
/dev/root                 8320      8320         0 100% /
/dev/nandflash          251919    102992    136127  43% /upgflash
/dev/sda1              2880416   1078268   1802148  37% /mnt/usb1_1
```

and the output of the cat /proc/filesystems command:

```
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   debugfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   usbfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   inotifyfs
        ext3
        squashfs
nodev   ramfs
        vfat
nodev   fuse
        fuseblk
nodev   fusectl
```

and the output of the cat /proc/partitions command:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

  31     0        256 mtdblock0
  31     1        512 mtdblock1
  31     2       8826 mtdblock2
   8     0    3942400 sda
   8     1    2888608 sda1
   8    16     256000 nflashb
```

and the output of the cat /proc/diskstats command:

```
  31    0 mtdblock0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  31    1 mtdblock1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  31    2 mtdblock2 236 3876 8224 3310 0 0 0 0 0 3310 3310
   8    0 sda 5 7 19 124 0 0 0 0 0 124 124
   8    1 sda1 11 11 0 0
   8   16 nflashb 748 2937 29848 11605 423 878 2854 465219 0 36340 476824
```

and the output of cat /proc/devices command:

```
Character devices:
  1 mem
  2 pty
  3 ttyp
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
 10 misc
 13 input
 21 sg
 89 i2c
 90 mtd
180 usb
188 ttyUSB
189 usb_device
209 endpoint
242 fcache
248 bhal
249 commondrv
250 i2c_pca
251 usb_endpoint
252 usbmon
253 nvram
254 gpio

Block devices:
  8 sd
 31 mtdblock
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
```

and the output of the cat /proc/meminfo command:

```
MemTotal:       126080 kB
MemFree:         90392 kB
Buffers:          4508 kB
Cached:          15428 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:           9616 kB
Inactive:        14412 kB
SwapTotal:           0 kB
SwapFree:            0 kB
Dirty:               0 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:        4116 kB
Mapped:           3452 kB
Slab:             5344 kB
SReclaimable:     1152 kB
SUnreclaim:       4192 kB
PageTables:        520 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:     63040 kB
Committed_AS:     7740 kB
VmallocTotal:  1032148 kB
VmallocUsed:      3460 kB
VmallocChunk:  1027212 kB
```

note: i provided all of this information so that you could get the right answer that's safe and not extremely fragile. please test the answers that you type in here BEFORE you tell me to do something unreliable or derpy.